# sql server sum aggregate functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

suppose I have this record

```
empcode      net       year     month
602256     3479.97     2014       1
602256     33125.98    2014       1
602256     5247.11     2014       2
602256     7698.39     2014       2
602256     2941.46     2013       3
602256     5515.57     2014       3
602256     5758.68     2014       3
602256     4966.89     2013       4
602256     4984.06     2013       4
602256     5951.63     2014       4
602256     19861.04    2014       4
```

what i want to happen is that i want to sum the net with the same year and month hope you can help me thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [**GROUP BY**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms177673.aspx) clause:

```
SELECT SUM(net) FROM table GROUP BY [year],[month]
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple by Group By cluase. Also whatever you given in group by clause , you can define in select like below, which gives better idea for calculation.

> SELECT year, month, SUM(net) FROM table GROUP BY [year],[month]